# How to use a variable in a function that returns None?

Tags: python, function, backtracking

I have the following function, it is used to solve a sudoku grid. How can I change the code such that it returns the solved matrix so that I can use it for something else, instead of only printing it? The function basically uses recursion to try out all possible solutions for the sudoku grid and fills in a number if it belongs in a certain position. source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&t=455s

```
matrix = np.array([[9,0,7,   1,0,0,   0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,   0,0,0,   0,0,0],
                   [5,0,0,   3,0,0,   0,6,9],

                   [0,0,1,   6,5,0,   8,0,0],
                   [0,3,0,   0,8,0,   0,4,0],
                   [0,0,6,   0,3,9,   1,0,0],

                   [4,2,0,   0,0,6,   0,0,8],
                   [0,0,0,   0,0,0,   0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,   0,0,2,   5,0,7]])

def grid(i,j): # function which splits the matrix up into 9 grids
    if i < 3 and j < 3:
        return matrix[0:3,0:3]
    elif  i < 3 and 3 <= j < 6 :
        return matrix[0:3,3:6]
    elif  i < 3 and 6 <= j < 9 :
        return matrix[0:3,6:9]
    elif  3 <= i < 6 and j < 3 :
        return matrix[3:6,0:3]
    elif  3 <= i < 6 and 3 <= j < 6 :
        return matrix[3:6,3:6]
    elif  3 <= i < 6 and 6 <= j < 9:
        return matrix[3:6,6:9]
    elif  6 <= i < 9 and j < 3 :
        return matrix[6:9,0:3]
    elif  6 <= i < 9 and 3 <= j < 6 :
        return matrix[6:9,3:6]
    elif  6 <= i < 9 and 6 <= j < 9 :
        return matrix[6:9,6:9] #

def possible(i,j,n): # function which tells us if a number is possible in a certain position
    if all(matrix[i][m] != n and matrix[m][j] != n for m in range(9)) and n not in grid(i,j):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def solve(): # function which solves the puzzle and fills in correct digits
    global matrix
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                for n in range(1,10):
                    if possible(i,j,n):
                        matrix[i][j] = n
                        solve()
                        matrix[i][j] = 0
                return
    print(matrix)


solve()
```

I have tried to use `return matrix` but this just returns the original matrix

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? This code looks familiar, where is it from?

Comment: just return the matrix?

Comment: I am trying to create a GUI where the user inputs the starting numbers, hits enter, and the GUI displays the solved grid. however, when trying to use the function solve(), it returns None so I can't use the solved grid array to display the filled in grid, if that makes sense.. The code is from the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&t=455s

Comment: When I return the matrix, it returns the original matrix, unsolved...

Comment: Don't unconditionally reset square `(i, j)` immediately after calling `solve`; you would only do that if you need to backtrack.

Comment: @chepner wrong, watch the video

Comment: @chepner But the whole point of solving the matrix is by backtracking, so why should I not reset (i, j) after calling solve()?

Comment: In part, because after the recursive call, the puzzle may or may not be completely solved. If it is, you want to return immediately. If it isn't, *then* you reset to backtrack. As is, you *always* reset the value, even if `matrix[i][j] = n` was the correct assignment.

Comment: I recommend adding lots of calls to `print` to the function (or using a debugger) to trace what happens as you solve something simpler, like a nearly complete puzzle or a smaller, 4x4 puzzle.

Comment: @chepner, this is nit the case due to the ``` if matrix[i][j] == 0:``` statement. If the matrix is completely solved it will not pass this if statement, and thus it will not reset any correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are working on a global matrix. Somewhere deep down the recursive calls you find the solution (and print it) but when returning up the stack you reset all fields back to 0. (See chepner's comment.)

Given that you are coding in a "procedural style", why not use a second global variable (`solution` say) and assign a deep copy.

```
from copy import deepcopy

...


solution = deepcopy(matrix)
```

Of course you could also restructure the code in a more functional style.

Comment: @Walid: Happy to help! :) If your problem is solved, the usual flow on stackoverflow would be to "accept" the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ;) Cheers